# Why did Zeke change from an Eldia enemy to an Eldia ally?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Something I missed from the anime, or it wasn't explained, or it wasn't explained yet -- why did Zeke change from battling eldians to being their ally? I looked for an explanation in the wikia, but I couldn't find an answer there either. Is this explained in the manga? Why did Zeke change from an Eldia enemy to an Eldia ally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this explained in the manga?

yes.

> Why Zeke changed from an Eldia enemy to an Eldia ally?

**SERIOUS SPOILERS WARNING!!**

everything is going according to manga and you'll understand everything just in time.

I suggest you wait for the following episodes.

if you don't mind spoilers continue

> Zeke had a goal, from the begging of becoming the beast titan. he wanted to change All of the Eldians genes so they can never bear any children. he wants to do that to stop all of the Hate and wars in the world (I guess :D). So, to do that he needs to contact the founder titan. so I don't think he was an enemy to Eldia he was acting so he could achieve his goal in the proper time.

Comment: The way he mercilessly killed a lot of important eldian people doesnt make this plot twist very smooth

Comment: @Pablo yes, but actually no. in the future episode you'll see how merciless he'll become just to accomplish his goal. you can check (chapter 119 page 18) to see what kind of guy Zeke is.

Answer (score 1):

Zeke had a secret plan for Eldians all along. He calls himself a true Eldian restorationist. He always wanted to save all eldians just like his father and he climbed up the military ranks in Marley for the very same reason. And thanks to that he could reach out to Eren. It is explained well in the [Blog Here.](https://animehunch.com/2020/12/26/what-was-zekes-secret-plan-for-eldia-in-attack-on-titan/) and [Here](https://animehunch.com/2021/01/08/why-did-zeke-team-up-with-eren-the-survey-corps/)